# how we make selectable touchableOpectiy or view in React native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

- how we make selectable touchable or view in React native
  touch and select on view or you can say touchable opectiy
  [Like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XF5vE.png)

[t](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XF5vE.png)

Answer (score 1):

React Native has a built-in component named TouchableOpacity, you can import it from 'react-native'.

```
import { TouchbleOpacity, Text } from 'react-native';
```

implementation

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={() => alert('pressed')} >
   <Text>Press me</Text>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

The component accepts the `onPress` prop where you can change the state and if it has been pressed make the background color as you want.

Except for TouchableOpacity, there are some other Touchables too (https://reactnative.dev/docs/handling-touches).

NOTE: Touchables are like HTMLs button tag, if you want to handle after a View press for example, you need to wrap your  component inside a  component. (https://reactnative.dev/docs/pressable)